# How use the black mode permanently

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

Now I can use this function：`ResourceFunction["DarkMode"][]` to use the dark mode, but when I turn on Mathematica again, the black mode will not work. How can I set to use the black mode permanently.

Picture

[image]

Comment: And how can one turn it off again...?

Comment: The above mode can not be good for your eyes. I would use it with caution.

Comment: @Nasser care to explain why it's not good for your eyes?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher If you go to Format -> StyleSheet Default will be unselected...selecting this again will ask to destroy current settings, and will revert to default stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! =D

Comment: @morbo  `Dark themes can put more strain on your eyes in high-light conditions, since it washes out the text. 100% contrast (white text on a black background) is typically harder to read and may cause more eye strain` If you google the subject you could see about this. I can't handle black or dark background on computer screen, it leaves spots in my eyes and makes it hard to look at for long time. May be for younger people it is ok. I prefer light theme. light white background and black text.

Comment: @Nasser Ah! Yes, actually you're right. During the day I find dark themes with too high contrast or complete white on black terrible...generally I turn the black to some kind of weird very blackish brown and the white to a greyish thing to get around that with Dark Reader, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the default stylesheet as follows:

1. Go to menu: Format > Options Inspector
2. Set the scope dropdown menu to "Global Preferences"
3. Download the stylesheet notebook of ResourceFunction@"DarkMode" from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/70ry3x4pts92szr/DarkMode.nb?dl=0).
4. Set the `DefaultStyleDefinitions` path to wherever you saved the notebook.

[image]

5. Now when you do File > New (cmd + n), you will have what you want.

[image]

**Notes:**

- To undo this change simply set `DefaultStyleDefinitions` back to "Default.nb".